# C++ abstract class allocation error for a class which is not abstract

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I have a base class A and derived class B. I want to create an object of class B like

```
B *myB = new B();
```

but I got an error in the following code like "error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type". However, class B is not abstract class.

```
class A{
    public:
    A();
    virtual ~A();
    static void func1();
};

class B: public A{
    public:
    B(int myval);
    virtual ~B();
    void func2();
};
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Post some real code, first. Then we'll try to help.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from syntax errors in the examples, I think this is your problem:

```
class A{
 A();
 virtual ~A();
 static void func1();
 };
```

The constructor, destructor and `func1` are declared as `private`, so you can't create instance of this class. You should make them `public:` (at least constructor):

```
class A{
public:
 A();
 virtual ~A();
 static void func1();
 };
```

**Edit** As you told that they're actually public, this is the second issue I can see:

You're using default constructor for `B`

```
B *myB = new B();
```

but you only have `B(int)` constructor.

Comment: I actually defined all functionality of A and B under public.

Comment: I corrected as B *myB = new B(5); but still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will not generate default constructor if you provided your own constructor like you have done in class B. You will need to explicitly provide default constructor B.
You can add

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
  B();
  B(int);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nemanja has the gist of it but I would amend slightly per the latest OP updates

1. You should also make `A`'s and possibly `B`'s `destructor`'s either `public` or `protected`.
2. You probably want to make `A`'s `constructor` `protected` as well.

## Key Points for making AbstractBaseClasses

1. You should make the destructor `virtual` and `public`
2. You should probably make the `constructor` protected

These make it clear that someone can inherit from your class and that it is not to be constructed.  When they see it can't be publicly constructed it will help to clue them in that either there is a factory method or a pure-virtual such that its abstract.

Beyond this Nemanja pointed out the other problematic issue of using a constructor that wasn't going to exist.